# Calculating a partial sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, summation

can somebody help me to explain why the partial sum of
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{(j+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$

I really appreciate any help you can provide!

Comment: Try proving by induction :)

Comment: Rewrite it as a telescoping series

Comment: $j$ is the same as $j+1-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{(j+1)!}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{(j+1) - 1}{(j+1)!} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \bigl( \frac{1}{j!}
- \frac{1}{(j+1)!} \bigr) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^n (a_j - a_{j+1})$$
Hence
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{(j+1)!} = (a_1 - a_2) + (a_2-a_3) + \ldots + (a_{n} - a_{n+1}) = $$
$$=a_1 - a_{n+1} =1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.$$

Comment: perfect, thank you!